# How to fix java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for JDBC:ODBC:Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, java-7

I have a project in Java 7 and need to run it. The problem is that when I try to run I get the error

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> JDBC:ODBC:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};

I tried most of the solutions suggested here but nothing is working. I tried to:

- Add Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); to my code and it gives me error --> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
- Check if I'm using Java 7 -> System.getProperty("java.version") gives me 1.7.0_75
- Added mysql-connector.jar

This is how I connect:

```
public static Connection GetConnection(String path) throws Exception {

    String db = "JDBC:ODBC:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+path;
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(db);

    return conn;
   
}
```

This is the full message (I'm using NetBeans):

[image: Error]

- Installed AccessDatabaseEngine

I never used ODBC, It may be that I need to configure anything in the 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool? Any suggestion?

Comment: Which Database you are using? MySQL or MS ACCESS?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam MS ACCESS

Comment: The URL is case sensitive, so you need to use `jdbc:odbc:`. However, the ClassNotFoundException suggests you're using Java 8 or higher, which no longer has the JDBC-ODBC bridge. Adding the mysql-connector.jar makes no sense, because that is the MySQL JDBC driver (protocol prefix `jdbc:mysql:`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If I'm using Java 8 or +, why System.getProperty("java.version") gives me 1.7.0_75?